При выделении нескольких файлов Проводник вылетает и перезагружается
Новое контекстное меню от Windows 11 работает, а "Показать дополнительные параметры" (Ctrl+ПКМ), которое вызывает старое "подробное" контекстное меню приводит к вылету и перезагрузке Проводника. Вероятно, это из-за какого-то ПО, которое я устанавливал где-то полгода назад.

В безопасном режиме проблема исчезает.
Отключение пунктов контекстного меню результатов не принесли. В ShellExView все сторонние выключены, в Autoruns тоже.
В msconfig>services все сторонние службы не выключались, отключал их через консоль, ничего не изменилось.
Команды sfc /scannow и dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth не принесли никаких результатов.
Файл от ProcDump через WinDbg, вроде, показал, что ругается на shel32.dll, (я не знаю надо это было или нет, но) его заменить с помощью dll-files.com само по себе не получилось, unlocker не сработал, через консоль в восстановлении системы (shift+restart), вроде, привело к тому, что проводник вообще перестал работать и запускаться. Но может это было из-за того, что я до этого реестр почистил на наличие лишних ячеек в папках shellex и т.д. А возможно и нет, потому что у shell32.dll до сих пор дата полмесяца назад. Вернуло всё на место sfc и/или dism.

explorer.exe_240727_012803.dmp https://disk.yandex.ru/d/s1zgkWYeN5mm0g
Что показывает WinDbg из этого файла от ProcDump:
MODULE_NAME: shell32
IMAGE_NAME: shell32.dll
STACK_COMMAND: ~51s; .ecxr ; kb
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: NULL_POINTER_READ_c0000005_shell32.dll!CRegistryVerbsContextMenu::QueryContextMenu

Монитор стабильности системы:
Application Name: Explorer.EXE
Application Version: 10.0.22621.3880
Application Timestamp: 0a9e5890
Fault Module Name: SHELL32.dll
Fault Module Version: 10.0.22621.3880
Fault Module Timestamp: 36c21d15
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset: 000000000009f52b
Версия ОС: 10.0.22631.2.0.0.256.48
Код языка: 1033
Additional Information 1: 502f
Additional Information 2: 502f7bfca51f60e08bb8f533e668795b
Additional Information 3: 97b6
Additional Information 4: 97b6b20922f2852f9284653da71d71c1

Extra info: Bucket ID: 9c9e0ab6cf22489217c128ec04e06e88 (1711694327536709256)


Если падает, значит в контекстном меню есть пункт, из-за которого оно падает. Причём этот пункт не попадает в основное меню. Удаляй поштучно и смотри, что будет.

Я именно этим и занимаюсь - разгребанием бардаков на компах пользователей. Уже 30 лет. Переустановка нормально и вчистую на моём ноуте 2012 года рождения занимает около 4 часов. Вы будете дольше письма писать на форумах.
Никакой ошибки, естественно, нет. Но для меня очевидно, что состояние Вашей ОС плачевно. Достаточно почитать всего лишь это: "...какого-то ПО, которое я устанавливал где-то полгода назад...", "...я до этого реестр почистил на наличие лишних ячеек в папках shellex...".
У меня клиенты подразделяются на три типа: 1) ничего не знают; 2) знают достаточно, чтоб не ломать; 3) знают слишком много. Первый и третий типы ломают компы достаточно быстро. Понятие дисциплины у них отсутствует. Анализ действий на компе тоже.
Грамотное развёртывание ОС включает в себя несколько фаз: 1) подготовка софта и компа; 2) инсталляция софта в соответствии с технологическими нормами; 3) дальнейшее регулярное грамотное обслуживание. Если переосмыслить себя и делать как положено, Вы становитесь волшебником. Как я. Я давно уже сплю, ибо ничего интересного, как в годы моей молодости когда Windows вылуплялся из яйца, уже НЕ происходит.
Перестановите софт, будет быстрее. Не слушайте советов "специалистов", они в данном случае бесполезны. Проведите ревизию софта, обновите всё до последних версий; обновляйте ОС и приложения Магазина в соответствии с рекомендациями Майкрософт; не ковыряйтесь в системе там, где не умеете; записывайте свои действия и фотографируйте их; прекратите "оптимизировать" и "удалять лишнее"; не делайте из Windows 11 Windows 7, устанавливая всякое паливо - какие-то там "возвращатели кнопки Пуск" и т.д. Если не можете измениться, вызовите "волшебника", который сделает всё по технологии - зачастую это тоже быстрее, дешевле и проще. Их мало, но они есть.

Привет!
В моём случае переустанавливать систему сейчас неактуально. Не понимаю почему постоянно про это пишут, не задумываясь о том, что у человека может не быть возможности это сделать сейчас. Я в гостях в деревне ещё на долгое время, тут очень ограниченные возможности по интернету; я не смогу ни скачать образ системы, ни потом переустанавливать кучу программ.
И также, не менее важный для меня факт: у меня ни раз был опыт, когда я отчаивался и хотел переустанавливать систему, но отлично помогли на форуме, тем самым сэкономив мне кучу времени и нервов, когда можно было гораздо удобнее.

"Какое-то ПО, которое я устанавливал где-то полгода назад" - да, я частенько устанавливаю пиратский софт, который раз в лет 5, да нарушит что-то такое (не столь значительное) в системе. И у меня были конкретные предположения, что именно за ПО, но почитав форумы, я понял, что это может быть что угодно, поэтому так "по-делитантски" написал, чтобы не сбивать с толку, возможно, лишней информацией.

Я и дальше буду эксперементировать и развиваться в разных софтах; движение - это жизнь; а раз в 5 лет обратиться на форум с какой-то ошибкой в системе - я это вообще не считаю проблемой. Тем более, на мой взгляд, это говорит о том, что несмотря на то, что я пренебрегаю некоторыми дисциплинами, у меня помногу лет работает всё отлично.
Спасибо за ответ!

Я б к этому часу уже закончил переустановку софта. Теперь о грустном:

"...я не смогу ни скачать образ системы..." - образ должен быть на компе.
"...да, я частенько устанавливаю пиратский софт..." - я не о пиратстве, а о том, чо надо помнить что, где и когда делалось. Для этого в инсталляционном блоке указывается версия каждой последней установленной программы.


Проблема у этого компьютера всё та же, я убеждён. Отсутствие подготовки, а именно отсутствие на компе инсталляционного блока, его актуальность, отсутствие ревизии и понимания сути информационной экосистемы, отсутствие элементарной дисциплины и отсутствие элементарного. но регулярного обслуживания.

Если проблемы нет, если можно и с таким состоянием БАЗОВОЙ составной части любой Windows - Проводника - можно вполне себе жить и "...у меня помногу лет работает всё отлично...", в чём же тогда проблема и зачем о ней писать тут? :-)))))))
